# How to edit the attached menu section for buddypress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I would like to know if there is a line of code I could use to add in functions.php or a file edit to add and remove some of the fields from the current section I have attached in WordPress.

It's a WordPress website running buddypress. This section has all the relevant menu items by default. I need to remove some from this and a new one if possible
This section is located in the top right section when hovered:

[image]

Comment: did you look on the buddypress site in the FAQ? Also without seeing any code it is impossible to figure anything out.

Comment: i am myself not sure how it is there but i need to edit it. seems like it is linked to wordpress backend as well. not only buddypress